# Excel - I want to lookup 1 table that is between a number range and is equal to a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My excel sheets has the following tables

```
MIN     MAX     name_a  name_b  name_c  name_d
0       50      5.6     5.35    5.1     4.85
50      100     5.55    5.3     5.05    4.8
100     200     5.45    5.2     4.95    4.7
200     500     5.4     5.15    4.9     4.65
500     1000    5.325   5.075   4.825   4.575
1000    2000    5.255   5.005   4.755   4.505
```

I have 2 more cells which correspond to names and a weight ie;

1) 433

2) name_c

The function would need two look up tables I believe;

1) The weight;
if weight is more than MIN & less than MAX then use this row

2) The name
if the name is equal to this, then use this column

I am struggling trying to combine 2 lookup functions to return me a value

The example should see that the value sits between 200 and 500 and should look at this row, and then it should see that the name is equal to name_c and therefore return me 4.9

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `SUMIFS` with an `INDEX/MATCH` to get the correct column.

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(C1:F7,,MATCH(H4,C1:F1,0)),A1:A7,"<="&H3,B1:B7,">="&H3)
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much

Comment: Great, glad to help out!